# Panda series from an "inverted" list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, series

There is a list of lists `idx_of_vals = [[ 3, 7, 10, 12, 9], [8, 0, 5, 1], [ 6, 4, 11, 2]]` (say, 13 randomly permuted integers from 0 to 12).

The desired output is a series `s`:

```
>>> s
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     0
4     2
5     1
6     2
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    0
11    2
12    0
Name: my_name, dtype: int64
```

I.e. the elements of `s` with indices from the 0-th element (`[ 3, 7, 10, 12, 9]`) of `idx_of_vals` have values 0 (i.e. its *index* in `idx_of_vals`), with indices from the 1-st element of `idx_of_vals` have values 1, and so on.

Current solution:

```
s = pd.Series(np.nan, index=np.arange(13), name='my_name')
for val, idx in dict(enumerate(idx_of_vals)).items():
    s.loc[idx] = val
s = s.astype(int)
```

Question: Is there a more efficient and pythonic way to reach the desired result *avoiding* `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing through pandas dataframes:

```
(pd.DataFrame(idx_of_vals)
   .stack()
   .droplevel(level=1)
   .sort_values()
   .index)
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Thank you for showing this type of notation! It's very similar to VBA'a `With`. I was looking for something like this for years.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a Series, `explode` and swap the index and values.

```
idx_of_vals = [[ 3, 7, 10, 12, 9], [8, 0, 5, 1], [ 6, 4, 11, 2]]

s = pd.Series(idx_of_vals).explode()
s = pd.Series(s.index, index=s).sort_index()
```

output:

```
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     0
4     2
5     1
6     2
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    0
11    2
12    0
dtype: int64
```

As a one-liner (python ≥3.8):

```
pd.Series((s:=pd.Series(idx_of_vals).explode()).index, index=s).sort_index()
```

Comment: Ah.....  assignment expression.... nice... plus one.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is not necessarily bad. Your current solution is faster than the currently accepted answer.

One thing that would make it more efficient and pythonic is not to preallocate the Series and then fill it, but to restructure the data and only then create the Series with it. For that, you can use a dictionary comprehension.

```
idx_of_vals = [[ 3, 7, 10, 12, 9], [8, 0, 5, 1], [ 6, 4, 11, 2]]
data = {val: idx for idx, lst in enumerate(idx_of_vals) for val in lst}
s = pd.Series(data, name='my_name').sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> s

0     1
1     1
2     2
3     0
4     2
5     1
6     2
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    0
11    2
12    0
Name: my_name, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try dict comprehension

```py
s = pd.Series(np.nan, index=np.arange(13), name='my_name')
s.update({val:idx for idx, vals in enumerate(idx_of_vals) for val in vals})
```

```
print(s)

0     1.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     0.0
4     2.0
5     1.0
6     2.0
7     0.0
8     1.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
11    2.0
12    0.0
Name: my_name, dtype: float64
```